# Seeking free data to calculate drive time based on traffic / congestion?

Tags: data, network-analyst, canada, traffic

I'm looking to calculate drive time contours based on traffic data. I have road network data (with distances and speed limits), but the client wants to take real live traffic/congestion data into account for a specific time period. The area of interest is Vancouver, BC.

Is there any freely available Esri data that could assist?

I'm very new to networking analysis.

Comment: There is a relatively new Stackexchange site dedicated to requests for data of all kinds. I recommend posting this question on [Open Data Stackexchange](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) instead of GIS Stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid, there are none. But Esri's Network Analyst supports something called [live / historic traffic](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/traffic-live.htm) which can be embedded into a network dataset. You might look for other 3rd party sources of this information, mine it, do some ETL, and then configure your network dataset to use this traffic information. This is quite a lot of work.

Your other option is to use a premium ArcGIS Online Routing Services which are backed both by the live and historical traffic. You can use those services either through a [web application](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/create-drive-time-areas.htm) or in ArcMap using the [Ready To Use Services toolbox](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/consuming-the-traffic-service-from-arcmap-10-2-.htm). Obviously, you cannot use your own network dataset so you cannot change the road segments costs. However, you would use a geoprocessing tool from this toolbox that would let you load barriers, specify the constraints to use, and many more. For generating the drive time zones, you would use the [GenerateServiceAreas](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/itemdesc-generate-service-areas.htm) tool.